# How do I change this so it fails the way I want?

Tags: java, file, csv, error-handling, opencsv

I think the following code stops if it encounters any error, period.

```
public static void exportDatapointsToCSV(List<Datapoint> datapointList, File exportDir) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy (h:mm a)", Locale.US);
    File file = new File(exportDir, "my_datapoints.csv");

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        csvWrite.writeNext(new String[]{"DATAPOINT_LABEL", "VALUE", "TIMESTAMP", "TIMESTAMP_FORMATTED", "NOTE"});

        for (Datapoint datapoint : datapointList) {
            String arrStr[] = new String[]{
                    datapoint.getLabel(),
                    datapoint.getValue() + "",
                    datapoint.getTimestamp() + "",
                    sdf.format(new Date(datapoint.getTimestamp())) + "",
                    datapoint.getNote()
            };
            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
        }
        csvWrite.close();
    }
    catch (Exception sqlEx) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }
}
```

But I want it to:

1. Throw an error and stop if it can't create the file to begin with.
2. If it encounters an error on a given row, log it but move onto the next row, rather than stopping the entire thing.

Do I just move the try/catch into the loop? Does that cover it?

Comment: change `catch (Exception sqlEx) {` to do certain action on certain `Exceptions`  Move the try/catch around certain code

Comment: @ScaryWombat What do you mean exactly? I am not sure what all these "certains" are

Comment: see my answer for more help

Comment: You don't have to wrap everything into one huge try/catch block. You can always do much finer exception handling. Wrap `createNewFile` and `writeNext` into their own try/catch blocks.

Comment: @tsolakp So nested try/catch blocks? Outer one throwing IOException, inner one throwing Exception?

Comment: It may not even be necessary to have a outer catc block.  Usually it is not best practices to `catch` `Exception` when there is a more specific exception to catch

Comment: No, just one after another. You seldom need to nest exception handling.

Comment: @ScaryWombat How do I know which exceptions I have to catch individually? Why can't I just catch Exception so I don't miss anything? Otherwise I risk having it get hung up on an error depending on what happens.

Comment: If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, then the IDE will tell you.  Otherwise the java code will not compile.  Looking at the Javadocs will give you the necessary information

Comment: That's one of the first things to understand anyway:don't do too many things in one method. Opening a file and processing content are two different responsibilities in the first place....

Comment: @GhostCat But isn't opening a file a fairly short/quick operation? It's not considered wasteful to use two functions for a single export?

Comment: It is about separation of concerns. When you have two methods, it is much easier to work with different catch blocks for example. And you don't worry about the overhead of calling 2 methods instead of 1 . worry about the readability of your code.

Comment: @GhostCat What's the correct way to separate them? Have one create the file and then pass that file object to the CSV function to make the CSVWriter / export the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception that you are catching is the Grandfather of all Exceptions - If you look at the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File)) you will see that the constructor `new FileWriter(file)` throws a `IOException`

So if you wanted *certain* action e.g. logging and quitting if this failed then try

```
 CSVWriter csvWrite = null;
 try {
         csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
 } catch (IOException ex) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    return; // or System.exit or what either
 }
```

Comment: What is an appropriate thing to do with errors here? Display them to the user or just silently dump them to a file?

Comment: I know nothing about your application.  If you silently dump them, how will the user feel?

Answer (score 0):

It is better if I show right in the code:

```
public static void exportDatapointsToCSV(List<Datapoint> datapointList, File exportDir) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy (h:mm a)", Locale.US);

    File file = null;
    try{ ( file = new File(exportDir, "my_datapoints.csv") ).createNewFile(); }
    catch(IOException e){throw new RuntimeException(e); }

    CSVWriter csvWrite = null;
    try {
        csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        csvWrite.writeNext(new String[]{"DATAPOINT_LABEL", "VALUE", "TIMESTAMP", "TIMESTAMP_FORMATTED", "NOTE"});

        for (Datapoint datapoint : datapointList) {
            String arrStr[] = new String[]{
                    datapoint.getLabel(),
                    datapoint.getValue() + "",
                    datapoint.getTimestamp() + "",
                    sdf.format(new Date(datapoint.getTimestamp())) + "",
                    datapoint.getNote()
            };
            try{ csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr); }
            catch(Exception e){LOG.error(e);}
        }
    }
    catch (Exception sqlEx) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }finally{
       if (csvWrite != null){
           csvWrite.close();
       }
    }
}
```